# v7 RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange() gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am getting

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(SourceFile:1654)
   at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12160)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14742)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(SourceFile:3097)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13588)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14430)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3252)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3070)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14739)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13588)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13635)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14430)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3252)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3070)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14739)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:534)
```

this crash but this is not happing always . some user getting this crash . i tried with different scenario i haven't got this crash

my code is

```
 adapter = new HAdapter(getContext(), mList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new     LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        list.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(5));
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(2);

   compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'){
    force = true;
      }
```

my xml is

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"

    android:visibility="visible" />
```

any idea why this crash is happing

Comment: try by removing `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(2);` if not necessory coz it's wont work well with all devices

Comment: i need it any alternative ?

Comment: try to set after list data load completly

Comment: found crash 
        android:scrollbars="vertical" if removed then working . so i have updated to 23.4