# Unable to bind data in Recycler view in android

Tags: android

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1545)
   at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:11567)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13931)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3037)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12832)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12876)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13621)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3037)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2901)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12827)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12876)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13621)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3037)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2901)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13928)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12832)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12876)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13621)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3037)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2901)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12827)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12876)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13621)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3037)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2901)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12827)
```

this is my Code

```
public class testclass extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<FlightAvilablityModel> flightAvilablityModelArrayList;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    JSONArray _jarArray;
    JSONObject _JsonObject;
    private FlightAvilablityAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        new flightAvilblity().execute();


    }


    class flightAvilblity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {


                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constant.NAME_SPACE, Constant.GET_FLIGHT_AVILABLITY_JSON);

                request.addProperty("Origin", "del");
                request.addProperty("Destination", "pat");
                request.addProperty("frmdate", "2017-03-03");
                request.addProperty("todate", "");
                request.addProperty("adl", "1");
                request.addProperty("chd", "0");
                request.addProperty("inf", "0");
                request.addProperty("travelclass", "E");
                request.addProperty("travelmodeway", "one");


                envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constant.URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call(Constant.NAME_SPACE + "/" + Constant.GET_FLIGHT_AVILABLITY_JSON, envelope);
                String result = ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getProperty(0).toString();

                _jarArray = new JSONArray(result);
                flightAvilablityModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < _jarArray.length(); i++) {
                    FlightAvilablityModel avilablityModel = new FlightAvilablityModel();
                    _JsonObject = _jarArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    avilablityModel.setFlightsegment_id(_JsonObject.getString("Flightsegment_id"));
                    avilablityModel.setImagefileName(_JsonObject.getString("ImagefileName"));
                    avilablityModel.setActualbasefare(_JsonObject.getString("actualbasefare"));
                    avilablityModel.setTax(_JsonObject.getString("tax"));
                    avilablityModel.setArrivalAirportCode(_JsonObject.getString("ArrivalAirportCode"));
                    avilablityModel.setArrivalDateTime(_JsonObject.getString("ArrivalDateTime"));
                    avilablityModel.setDepartureAirportCode(_JsonObject.getString("DepartureAirportCode"));
                    avilablityModel.setDepartureDateTime(_JsonObject.getString("DepartureDateTime"));
                    avilablityModel.setFlightNumber(_JsonObject.getString("FlightNumber"));
                    avilablityModel.setAdultFare(_JsonObject.getString("adultFare"));
                    avilablityModel.setClassType(_JsonObject.getString("timediff"));

                    flightAvilablityModelArrayList.add(avilablityModel);
                }


                Log.d("Response", result.toString());


            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            mAdapter = new FlightAvilablityAdapter(flightAvilablityModelArrayList);
            LinearLayoutManager verticalLayoutmanager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(testclass.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutmanager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

I am getting data in flightAvilablityModelArrayList described in testclass,   but when I bind data in `onpost Execute` method, then I am getting that Exception. I don't know why this Error is coming.

Please suggest me where am I doing wrong!

Comment: try to change your layoutmanager:  LlayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

Comment: did you check flightAvilablityModelArrayList length?

Comment: yes  i am getting 5 length @sasikumar

Comment: @Divyesh its activity not Fragemnt how i will set getActivity()

Comment: in your xml remove line android:scrollbars="verticle" if you use. and instead of getactivity use testclass.this

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
 i did same thing  also i added testclass.this

Comment: did you add RecyclerView in gradle

Comment: i mean remove android:scrollbars="vertical" and make sure all your library has same version\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781896/v7-recyclerview-computeverticalscrollrange-gives-nullpointerexception

Comment: yes its correct @Divyesh THANX

Comment: which one solved your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering Problems: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in Android Studio 1.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005644/rendering-problems-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-android-support-v7-widget)

Comment: after removing remove android:scrollbars="vertical"

Comment: okk. ..........

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollbars as vertical in RecyclerView

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

In your gradle check once you added following dependencies

```
dependencies {   
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'    
}
```

Comment: i did same thing @sasikumar  still same Error

Comment: then try once recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));